# How to make go search for packages in GOPATH while importing a package?

Tags: go, import, gopath

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "controller/userhandler"   //not able to import this custom package      
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"                                         
    "net/http"                                                         
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"                                               
  _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

func main(){
}
```

The code below shows that Go is only searching for packages in GOROOT. After not finding `controller/userhandler` in **GOROOT**, ideally, it should look for packages in **GOPATH** but it does not.

I have already set **GOPATH** to my workspace path which includes the folders: `bin`, `src`, and `pkg`.

```sh
$ go build main.go                                                           
main.go:5:2: package controller/userhandler is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/controller/userhandler)
```

Comment: can you please show your code?

Comment: Go uses modules by default (see [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), and the [Modules wiki page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)). Without a [mre] we can't tell exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62573465/7715823

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run `go mod init MODULE_NAME` (if the project is outside **GOROOT** or **GOPATH**) or just simply `go mod init` (if the project is inside **GOROOT or GOPATH**). The command should be run on the root folder of your project. This would create a `go.mod` file that would enable **go** to resolve your packages.